# Add an image to a bound datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid that is databound, but before the binding happens, I use the datagrid loadingrow event handler to colour the background of each row depending on the condition met.  I want to remove this and I have decided to add a datatemplatecolumn (STATUS) to the datagrid which is not bound but I am hoping to populate with an appropriate image depending on the condition met using LoadingRow event.  The reason I am not using a DataTemplate is due to the date comparison that is required to determine the correct iamge.

I have looked at several examples but have no idea how to add the image to the cell on the Status column to include an image for each row.  I would be extremely grateful for some guidance.

Thanks for your help as always,

XAML

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="schDataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" LoadingRow="schDataGrid_LoadingRow" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="STATUS" />  <-- Add Image Here -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ITEMNUMBER}" Header="ITEMNUMBER" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CODE}" Header="CODE" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DESC}" Header="STD DESCRIPTION" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DESCRIPTION}" Header="UNIQUE DESCRIPTION" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SERIALNUMBER}" Header="SERIAL NUMBER" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C#

```
private void schDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
            var row = e.Row;
            DataRowView rView = row.Item as DataRowView;
            string DUEDATE = rView["DUEDATE"].ToString();

            DateTime now = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            DateTime compareDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DUEDATE);
            TimeSpan difference = now - compareDate;

            if (difference.Days <= 0)
            {
                Image image = new Image();
                var uriSource = new Uri(@"/main;component/Images/Icons/green.gif", UriKind.Relative);
                image.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource);

                //Now Add the image to the DataGridTemplateColumn["STATUS"]
                rItem["STATUS"] = image;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could still use the DataTemplate if the Status is part of the same object you are binding to the grid like this :

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <Image Source="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToImageConvertor}}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Include the reference for your converter your XAML resources:

```
<converter:StatusToImageConvertor:Key="StatusToImageConvertor"/>
```

This is how your converter will look like :

```
 public sealed class StatusToImageConvertor : IValueConverter
{

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

    // The value here is your status being passed from XAML binding
        if (value is string)
        {
           if(value == "x") return "image1.png";
       if(value = "y") return "image2.png";
       else return "image3.png";

    }
    else return string.empty;   

    }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps you

Comment: Thanks for your help Praveena, I am having a problem with the reference for the converter, I get the following error "Error 1 ''Converter' is an undeclared prefix. Line 6, position 10.' XML is not valid."

Comment: you have to add the reference in your XAML like this first: xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:<namespace of your converter>;assembly=<assembly name of your converter>"